# Linear Dependency of two functions

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

How the functions $f(x) = x^2$ and $g(x) = x|x|$  are linearly independent for $-\infty \lt x \lt \infty$?

My Try:- I first divided the interval in two parts $x \le 0$ and $ x \gt 0$. Then I calculated the Wronskian of the two functions separately which came out to be zero in both the cases. Then why these functions are linearly independent? Is is  so because we are not able to find any nonzero constants c and k for which $cf(x)  + kg(x) \ne 0 $. And if answer is yes, then why do they contradict with Wronskian?

Comment: Wronskian $= 0$ does not imply that functions are linearly dependent.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose there are nonzero a and b such that for all x, $ax^2 + bx|x| = 0$, which is the definition for linear dependence. Plug in $x=1$ and $x=-1$ to get $a + b = 0$ and $a - b = 0$. Thus, $b=0$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: But Why we get Wronskian of the two functions always zero? Is it not true that If two functions are linearly dependent then their Wronskian is zero?

Comment: Well, consider x as positive. Then the Wronskian matrix is [x^2 x^2; 2x 2x]. If the functions are dependent, then the determinant is the Wronskian must be zero, and if we take the determinant, we see that is indeed zero.

Comment: Then it means they are linearly dependent, don't it?

Comment: Here’s the problem: my proof assumes that x is positive, and thus proved that they’re linearly dependent over all the positive reals; you could prove it similarly for the negative reals. But it’s not true for both.

Comment: It is true that we can not get af(x) + bg(x) = 0 for both positive reals and negative reals at a same time for non zero constants a and b. But we get Wronskian of the two zero for all real x's positive as well as negative. Then to which result should i give priority:- Wronskian zero means linearly dependent or to af(x) + bg(x) = 0 for non zero a and b means linearly dependent!!?

Comment: The Wronskian being zero means it’s linearly dependent *over all positive $x$* but not over all $x$.